# MySQL grant syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I tried to run this SQL query:

```
grant all on `mch`.* to 'admin'@'localhost' identified by '123456';
```

but it complains:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by '123456'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version you are using, this is no longer allowed.

> As of MySQL 5.7.2, if the account already exists, IDENTIFIED WITH is
>   prohibited because it is intended only for use when creating new
>   accounts.